# How to change the URL that contains "#!" to "d/" in Java?

Tags: java

Ok, here is my problem. I am building the Ajax Web app & to make my webapp to be seen by Google spider, I need to use the url that contain hashbang "`#!`". For example, my url could be like this:

```
mydomain.com/#!getCustomer
mydomain.com/#!getOrder
....
These url look pretty ugly & beside Google adword does not allow # in the url so I can't advertise my url in Goolge.
```

Thus, I want that everytime user go to the above link, the system will change "#!" to "d/", so that users will see these:

```
mydomain.com/d/getCustomer
mydomain.com/d/getOrder
....
```

**Note**: even the url doesn't contain "`#!`", but the system still be able to let Google spider to index my website.

So, I use FilterServlet to do that:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String fullURLQueryString = getFullURL(httpRequest);
    System.out.println(fullURLQueryString); // test url
    if ((fullURLQueryString != null) && (fullURLQueryString.contains("#!"))) {
         fullURLQueryString=fullURLQueryString.replace("#!", "d/");
         request.getRequestDispatcher(fullURLQueryString).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

However, the system does not recognize the part "`#!`" when capturing the  `fullURLQueryString`

So the `System.out.println(fullURLQueryString);` only print out the `mydomain.com` & it ignores completely the part `#!getCustomer` or `#!getOrder`.

Did i do anything wrongly here?

Can you fix it?

Comment: The fragment is only visible client-side and usually used to navigate in your current document. The browser doesn't send it with your request

Comment: i heard someone said using HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo() to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use `#!`, if your web application doesn't use client-side generated content.  If your URLs do not currently contain `#`, this functionality is of no interest for your.

In typical scenario in which this is useful user goes to page: `http://example.com/#page1`.
The browser requests `http://example.com/` (notice `#page1` is not in the request). After the page is loaded, client side JavaScript examines the part after `#` and downloads additional content.

Google bots do not support JavaScript and cannot download any additional content. For them, every page `http://example.com/#page1`, `http://example.com/#page2` ... looks the same.

To fix this, `#!` syntax was introduced. You can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

Comment: what r u talking about/? i am using "#!"?

Comment: @Tum Why do you want to use `#!`? Google spider will work perfectly fine for urls like this: `mydomain.com/d/getCustomer`.

Comment: at this moment. i am using "mydomain.com/#!getCustomer"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this server-side because browsers never send the URL *fragment* (the `#` and everything after it) to the server. You can do this replacement only with client-side JavaScript:

```javascript
if (location.href.match(/\/#!/)) {
    location.replace(location.href.replace(/\/#!/, '/d/'));
}
```

Comment: can client change the url name?

Comment: @Tum What do you mean URL "name"?

Comment: why /\/#!/) doesn't have any "" double quotation? the eclipse mark Red err.

Comment: @Tum The code I posted is JavaScript, not Java. Put it in a JavaScript file or `<script>` block in HTML.

Comment: ur solution work but it did not show the customerPage, instead it show the home page. So it seems that the client changed the url before it actually show the ajax page & that is why it just show the home page. I heard someone said using getPathInfo in serverside. U can see this example https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-web-toolkit redirects to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit

Comment: @Tum There is no server-side solution, because the server cannot possibly see the `#!`. The link you posted does the *opposite* of what you're doing: it redirects from a real path to a hashbang path (the server *can* do that). Can you please provide an example of the URL you are accessing and the URL that the script I posted redirects it to?

Comment: maybe use Name pattern to map "/d/" to "#!" & then use the filter to change "/d/" to "#!".. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am using GWT platform, not sure if u know GWTP, but  I think use name pattern is the right way to do

Answer (score -1):

You should be constructing your URLs with the `URL` class (not a `String`).

Here is the official Java 8 Documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your getFullURL() method. Instead you should use getRequestURL().